# Open test results from a Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have a Visual Studio extension that runs tests in an external service and gets the results back as a .trx file. In the extension code, how do I display the Test Results window and open the result file there?  Similarly as would happen if I clicked the .trx file externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not loading the data into the window directly, but a more general solution is to open the file through ItemOperations:

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(pathToTheTrx);
```

This will of course work with any type of file Visual Studio identifies.

Answer (score 0):

ten years later, I’m doing a very similar thing, I have figured out how to load tests into VS2022 into the test results explorer, but now I’m trying to figure out how to open a selected test directed to the file and line it’s located at.

I wonder if this is even possible, or if that kind of functionality is hidden from end users.